# how to hold the output of os.system("command") in the terminal/cmd and used it in other command?

Tags: python-3.x, shell, operating-system

I am trying to execute os.system("command") and then the other command tries to read it but cannot get the output.
A sample of the above question is given below

example:

`os.system("script='policy/policy.script'")`

`os.system("echo [script] The policy script is \"$script\"")`

**the expected output is :**

`[script] The policy script is 'policy/policy.script'`

Answer (score 0):

If I do understand you correctly, you can try this:

```
import os

stream = os.popen("echo [script] The policy script is \"$script\"")
data = stream.read()
print(data)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However, I am not getting the desired output.

This should be the output :
`[script] The policy script is 'policy/policy.script'`